# Extract the hex number digits using bitwise operators

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Given int a=0x1234
print 4321 using bitwise operations,I did like this is there any better way of doing this.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int val = 0x1234;
    int mask = 0x000F;
    ///trying to print 4
    int ans = val&mask;
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    val=val>>4;
    ans = val&mask;
    cout<<ans<<endl;
    val=val>>4;
    ans=val&mask;
    cout<<ans<<endl;

}
```

Comment: What about a loop?

Comment: Are you asking for a code review of code which basically does what it is supposed to do?

Comment: What should be printed for `int a=0xABCD`?

Comment: use loop, it's concise and compact

Answer (score 1):

I think, this certainly looks better than yours:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    unsigned val = 0x12AB;
    std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase;
    do std::cout << (val & 0xF) << '\n';
    while (val >>= 4);
    // std::cout << std::nouppercase << std::dec;
}
```

Prints:

```
B
A
2
1
```

To print in the characters in lowercase, just remove `std::uppercase`.
To print `A` as `10`, `B` as `11` ..., completely remove line `4`.
Uncomment line `7` if you intend to print other numbers in your code in regular format.

*UPDATE* : Switched to `do-while` from `while` to handle `val = 0`.

Comment: is 0xf is same as 0x000f

Comment: @user10891599 Yeah it is the same. Preceding `0`s doesn't matter.

Comment: doesn't really matter but its not necessary to set `std::hex` for every iteration of the loop

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    int a = 0x1234abd;

    while( a > 0 ) {
        printf( "%c", hex[a & 0xf] );
        a >>= 4;
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ ./a.out 
dba4321
```

---

this is an answer to the comment from `brc-dd` -- if I was writing this code from the scratch, I would output the number to the string using:

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::hex << int_value;
std::string hex( stream.str() );
```

And then reverse the string using:

```
string reversed(hex.rbegin(), hex.rend());
```

But OP wanted to use bitwise ops....

Comment: @lenik Why not just use `%x` or `%X` instead of `%c` and replace `hex[a & 0xf]` with just `a & 0xf`? No need of the `hex` array.

Comment: can you tell me the meaning of a & 0xf?

Comment: @user10891599 Firstly, you had used the same logic in your code. Did it just came to your mind and you used it even without knowing it?!! Secondly, the answer to your question : it performs bitwise AND operation of `a` and `0xf`. In this case, the operation is giving us the last digit of hex representation of `a`.

Comment: @brc-dd answered in the answer.

Comment: @lenik I think you misinterpreted my comment. I never said to write from scratch or without using bitwise operations. I was just suggesting to use `%x` as format specifier in `printf`.

Comment: @brc-dd please, read the question title: "Extract the hex number digits using bitwise operators" -- using `printf` formats does not do exactly that.

Comment: @lenik You are still not understanding. See [this code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8PI0ojDYMv8Hwg40).

Answer (score -3):

I think you should just declare 1 more variable and initialize it to `Zero` and then multiply `ans` with `pow(16,i++)` each time you print or calculate bits value.

Please try below code.. I compiled and run it with g++.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int val = 0x1234;
    int mask = 0x000F;
    ///trying to print 4
    int i = 0;
    int ans = val & mask;
    cout << ans * pow(16, i++) << endl;
    val = val >> 4;
    ans = val & mask;
    cout << ans * pow(16, i++) << endl;
    val = val >> 4;
    ans = val & mask;
    cout << ans * pow(16, i++) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I tried and got `4 48 512` (newline instead of spaces).

Comment: just don't use `endl` in print statement

Comment: even without the newlines it doesn't produce the correct result. Also [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: It's not necessary but it is used so no problem I did no change.. I just change what is required got get equivalent decimal number we need to add them

Comment: Your code prints `4 48 512` which isn't quite `0x1234` backwards which was the aim of the OP's question